# Generate TextView dynamically on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dynamic, textview

I am totally new to Android Studio with Java, I am familiar only with html , CSS , JavaScript and PHP.

I am building an app and I need it to generate a list of items from an array. How do I do that?

I tried to do simply this, but nothing shows up in the activity!

public void view(View v){

```
    TextView t = new TextView(viewAuto.this);

    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

t.setText("PIPPO");
}

Comment: For listing you can move to recycler view or list view or you can simply display text in text view using for loop like list.forEach { t.setText("Your text\n")}

Answer (score 0):

in Android, in the first step, you put each feature of the palette in xml, you have to **identify** it in java files
like this

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

Then you can apply the changes
What you did was to create an object from textView, which is wrong in the case of material design
Rather, it applies to classes, fragments, adapters, etc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need first create XML layout and create TextView component there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

then you go code and get text view, and append all the strings using \n so that at the end of each string it goes to new line

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val textView = findViewById<R.id.text_view>()

        val yourList = listOf("Here", "Will", "Be", "Your", "Strings")

        yourList.forEach { textView.text = textView.text + it + "\n" }
    }

}
```

For showing your items in a scrollable list, you need to use `ScrollView`, for better performance you need to use `RecyclerView`